# What modern devices are susceptible to impurity?

Tags: technology, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

I'm especially interested in computing devices like laptops/smartphones and vehicles like cars and trains.

Comment: This is a really big deal.  Most of them aren't waterproof, so once they're tamei they're permanently ruined for any purpose that requires them to be tahor (e.g. infrastructure of the Beis Hamikdash, or kohanim driving home from the mikveh to eat terumah).

Comment: all metallic devices are suceptible to impurity. only kle even and pshute kle ets don't mekabel tuma

Comment: Not everything is made of metal. Some are made of plastic. Even those that are made of metal are made of composites, which are subject to a Machaloket Acharonim.

Comment: @Heshy More and more are waterproof (for several years now).

Comment: @DonielF not cars, as far as I know.  And they're typically going to become tamei midras pretty quickly.  For mikdash phones, yes I agree the gizbarim can just get waterproof ones.

Comment: @Heshy How much liquid is required to be machshir something? Surely a car wash is sufficient; does the inside need to get wet, too?

Comment: @donielf machshir?  That's something completely different.  To make it tahor it has to be completely submerged.  I think the inside too but I might be wrong there.  But regardless cars get ruined in floods and I imagine a mikveh would do the same thing.  Maybe there's a maayan somewhere that would work but it seems unlikely to me.

Comment: @Heshy Ah, I misread your original comment as saying that once they’re susceptible to tumah they’re permanently ruined. I believe you are correct then.